# How do I use interpn on SciPy to upsample upsample a 4d fMRI .mat file?

Tags: python, scipy

I have a 4d .mat file which gives X,Y,Z, and T for an fMRI file that takes scans at 1.5, 2, and 3hz.  I want to interpolate the lower sampling rate images so they are all at 3hz.  I have tried using interpn in scipy, but I don't understand the arguments for it.  Its dimensions are 80x64x33xn, depending on the sampling rate.

Comment: Show what you have tried

Answer (score 0):

Since you are only interpolating the time axis you are probably better served with [interp1d](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.interpolate.interp1d.html#scipy.interpolate.interp1d). Assuming your 4d data are in `D` and your various time grids are `T15`, `T2` and `T3` it should be as simple as

```
from scipy.interpolate import interp1d
# next line assumes interpolation along the last dimension of D
# if your data are arranged differently, use axis kwarg
f = interp1d(T15, D)
Dprime = f(T3)
```

where `Dprime` are the upsampled data.